What is covering my stone wall and how to repair?
In the photos you can see some kind of concrete rendering or something covering the top of my doorway, and also a layer peeling off the side of a window.
Does anyone know what this most likely is?  Is it just concrete?  I will be having the entire wall repaired soon and would be good to know how to get this in ideal condition.  There is a steel beam holding up the doorway too, which is very rust with damp now.



It looks like paint

I'm talking about the stuff under the paint :/

This looks like a thick coat of parging tooled to create a stone effect or fill in the gaps from the stonework. The work over the door looks like a stucco application of the same material.

Thank you.  Never heard of the term parging before!
